# How do I make an old commit the current master commit with git?

Tags: git, github

Here are my commits:

A B C

With C being the current commit. I want things to look like this on origin:

A B C A

So A is my current commit, but B and C are retained. I currently have the repo cloned with C being the current commit. What do I need to do next to get origin how I want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commits 'B' and 'C' are progressive states of the branch's history. To reset to 'A' without losing 'B' or 'C' locally, just use a new branch on origin:

```
git checkout -B new-branch master
git reset --hard <A_commit_hash>
git push origin new-branch
```

'B' and 'C' will be retained on 'master', so you can `git cherry-pick <commit_of_B_or_C>` or `git merge master` without trouble.

If you really want 'B' and C', but want to reset 'master' to 'A', and have thought through the consequences of forcibly overwriting your remote:

```
git branch archived-master master ;# create 'archived-master' branch
git reset --hard A ;# reset master to 'A' state
git push -f origin master ;# overwrite remote's master
```

That'll save 'B' and 'C' locally on the 'archived-master' branch.

I would avoid `git revert` for this. Revert commits make commands like `git bisect` and `git rebase` more difficult, and if you ever want to reuse 'B' and 'C' it's harder for a human to parse the history.

Comment: How do I push new branch to origin master?

Comment: Now that's a different question... You could forcibly overwrite it with `git push origin -f new-branch:master` or issue `git reset --hard A` on 'master' and forcibly push it up (again, `git push -f origin master`) but both have consequences and should be thought through.

Answer (score 3):

`git revert B C`

(this will add two commits, but the state of your tree will be as it was at A)